# WPF | WindowFormHost | WebBrowser | Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

I am trying to write an application where users can highlight text in a browser and mark the contents via the context menu.  I have a WPF application and I am using the WindowsFormHost with a Windows Forms WebBrowser so I can have a custom context menu.  My problem is that I cannot get the Click event to fire.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitalizeComponent();            
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();              
        Browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu BrowserContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();       
        System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem MenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
        MenuItem.Text = "Take Action";             
        MenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MenuItem_Click);
        BrowserContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(MenuItem);
        Browser.ContextMenu = BrowserContextMenu;
        WindowsFormsHost.Child(Browser);               
    }

    //THIS DOESN'T FIRE!?!?!?
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out.  Moved everything to Main_Loaded and it works like a charm.

Comment: Write an answer to you own question and then mark it as the answer then. Don't just edit the question title to include **solved**,.

Comment: For that matter, it's not even a title.

Answer (score 0):

Moved everything to Main_Loaded and it works